# Formatjs / react-intl with Vite

Tags: vite, react-intl, formatjs, babel-plugin-react-intl

Formatjs provides a [babel plugin](https://formatjs.io/docs/tooling/babel-plugin) for modules that use `react-intl` to inject message IDs and remove `description`. How can I use it with [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/)?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using @vitejs/plugin-react, you can specify a .babelrc or a babel.config.js.

```
import React from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

...

plugins: [
  React({
    babel: {
      babelrc: true
    }
  }),

  ...

]
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vitejs/plugin-react